# Axios ou Ajax em vue.js para realizar requisições ao servidor laravel como api?

Tags: ajax, laravel, vue.js, axios

Tenho uma dúvida que não consegui solucionar pesquisando na internet.
Eu uso o ajax para realizar requisições há um bom tempo, agora estou programando em vue.js, e utilizo axios, gostaria de saber se há alguma diferença entre os 2, qual o mais ideal, não consegui criar uma opinião sobre isso ainda. Qual vocês preferem? Eu prefiro ajax.

Comment: Vue recomenda axios acredito que seja porque o axios é baseado em `promises`.

Comment: AJAX e Axios são coisas diferentes. AJAX é o mesmo que requisição assíncrona. Axios é uma **biblioteca para realizar requisições assíncronas**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sigla Ajax em português significa JavaScript e XML Assíncronos. De forma bem resumida, trata de requisições http sem a necessidade de refresh. Em outras palavras qualquer aplicação que use AJAX pode enviar e receber dados do servidor sem precisar recarregar a página inteira.

Perceba que AJAX está mais pra um conceito, que é implementado pelo JQuery. 
Como o Vue.js não o faz nativamente, faz-se necessário a utilização de uma biblioteca, que nesse caso é o axios.

Quanto ao diferencial, destaca-se o fato de ele ser baseado em promises, mas existem varios outros pontos que nos dão mais poder sobre as requisições, por exemplo os intercepts.

Fontes: 
https://www.hostinger.com.br/tutoriais/o-que-e-ajax/ 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios